# Fix div position in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am using the same form on two different pages. On the first one every div is tidy in the desired position. On the second page, there is a select that only appears after a change (jquery trigger), which causes the div below it to appear first on the right but after the trigger it moves on the left. I'd like the div which contains radio buttons to be on the left side at all times, just like it is on the first page. The part that I'd like to fix is `#center-add-new-event-form .container-field input[type=radio]`.

This is the css.

```css
#center-add-new-event-form,
#center-add-new-event-form * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#center-add-new-event-form {
    padding: 20px 10px 0px;
}

#center-add-new-event-form .container-field {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;    
    vertical-align: top;    
}

#center-add-new-event-form .container-field label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#center-add-new-event-form .container-field input[type=text],
    #center-add-new-event-form .container-field select {
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 7px;
    display: block;    
    width: 100%;
}

#center-add-new-event-form .container-field input[type=radio]
{
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 7px;
    display: block;    
    width: 100%;
}


#center-add-new-event-form .center-error-message {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: darkred;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.center-event-actions {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 20px 20px 15px;
    text-align: right;

}

.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after {  
    display: table;  
    content: " ";
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #center-add-new-event-form .container-field {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }   
}
```

```html
<form id="center-add-new-event-form" class="clearfix">



    <div class="container-field" style="width: 100%">
            <label></label>
            <div id="center-request-details">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-field">
            <label for="teaching-requests"></label>
            <select id="input-teaching-requests" name="teaching-requests" class="create-request-event ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <option value=""></option>

                        <option value=""></option>
            </select>
            <span class="center-error-message"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="container-field">
            <label for="request-date"></label>
            <input type="text" name='request-date' class="create-request-event event-datepicker ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <span class="center-error-message"></span>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="container-field">
        <label for="teaching-start-time"></label>
        <input type="text" name="teaching-start-time" class="create-request-event event-timepicker text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <span class="center-error-message"></span>
    </div>

    <span class="clearfix"></span>

    <div class="container-field">
        <label for="teaching-end-time"></label>
        <input type="text" name="teaching-end-time" class="create-request-event event-timepicker text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <span class="center-error-message"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="container-field">
        <label for="teaching-teacher"></label>
        <div id='contanier-teacher-selection'>

        </div>
        <span class="center-error-message"></span>

    </div>           
    <div class="container-field pull-left" align="left">
        <label for="recursive-events" align="left">
        <input type="radio" align="left" name="recursive" value="daily"/>Daily
        <input type="radio" align="left" name="recursive" value="weekly"/>Weekly
        <input type="radio" align="left" name="recursive" value="monthly"/>Monthly
        </label>
    </div>
    <span class="center-error-message"></span>        
</form>

<div class="center-event-actions">
    <button id="cancel-add-new-event" class='button' data-izimodal-close="" data-izimodal-transitionout="bounceOutDown"></button>
    <button id="add-new-event" class='button button-primary'></button>
</div>
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oOWq.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fjZI.png)

Comment: Probably easiest to solve if you don’t hide the element using display:none (which is what jQuery’s .hide does), but using visibility:hidden instead.

Comment: .hide is not used, there is a condition. That displays a php echo before a change trigger. You open the window the select is not there but the echo'd line, you change an input from the other divs and then the select div appears on the screen, which in turn moves the radio divs on the left.

Comment: Please show the actual relevant code for this then.

Comment: I added screenshots of before and after to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is caused by container-field <= width: 50% and float
so when this div appears it appears next to last one
the solution add

```
<span class="clearfix"></span>
```

before the the element with radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
#center-add-new-event-form .container-field input[type=radio]:before
{
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 7px;
    display: block;    
    width: 100%;
}

#center-add-new-event-form .container-field input[type=radio]:after
{
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 7px;
    display: block;    
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```